# Deploing Rails App on other Port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, port, virtualhost, production

simple question, How can I deploy my Rails Application into a port of my website? I know i can specify the port when running using Mongrel or Webrick, but this time, I have to deploy it into production. I think passenger can manage this but I dont know how. I tried search but still I can't find the solution. Please help :)

Thanks!

Follow-up:
I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and my Passenger runs with Apache.

Comment: You should also specify which Linux distro you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Passenger with Apache or nginx. It will use the default port, 80. You can change this in the config file based on which web server you use.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Apache on Linux Ubuntu 10.04LTS, what config file should I modify? I changed my /etc/apache2/ports.conf. I added Listen 8080 and also modify my sites-enabled/default, I added the VirtualHost on *:8080 but still port 8080 is unaccessible :(

Answer (score 0):

```
# HTTPS server
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 8080;
  server_name *.host.com;

  root /home/app/public_html/host_production/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root html;
  }
  location = /404.html {
      root html;
  }
  error_page 503 @503;
  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }

    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  try_files $uri /system/maintenance.html @passenger;


  location @passenger {
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_min_instances 5;
    rails_env production;
  }


  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }


  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
          deny all;
  }


  access_log /dev/null;
  error_log /dev/null;
}
```

[nginx+passenger config](https://gist.github.com/711913)

Comment: Thanks mikhailov, but I need the Passenger config for Apache.

Comment: so you need only help with httpd configure? Use **Listen 80 Listen 8081** (2 lines here)

Comment: I got it. I just dont know why port 2011 is not working. I manage to run my app on port 8080 and 3000 :) Thanks!

Comment: @ikenn ports upto 4096 are inaccessible